# asp net core activate a controller and action with href?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, href

I have a controller with Index action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private FlyRepository rep;
    private UserSession uSession;
    public HomeController(FlyRepository theRep, UserSession theus)
    { rep = theRep;
        uSession = theus;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Index(int City=-1)
    {

        ViewBag.Title = "Home";
        IQueryable<Locations> locs = rep.GetLocations();
        ViewBag.Locations = locs.ToList();

        var aFormUser = (uSession.SearchInput == null) ? new FrmUser() : uSession.SearchInput;
        if (City != -1)
        {
            long carouselLocID = rep.GetCarouselLoc(City);
            if (carouselLocID != -1) aFormUser.FlightDestID = carouselLocID;
        }


        return View("Index", aFormUser);

    }
```

In the startup.cs the routing is set so:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

And in my Views/Home/ folder I have the Index page view to which this controller is tied.

Now in my Index.cshtml I want to add a href to the same page invoking the controller and the action.
For example

```
<a href=""> Roma </a>
```

What to include in the Href in order to activate the Home controller and the index action?
I tried:

```
<a href="Home/Index/?City=0">Roma</a>
<a href="Home/Index/?City=1">Firenze</a>
```

But that works only the first time. The first click on Roma produces the url:

```
http://localhost:60335/Home/Index/?City=0
```

The second click on Firenze causes a wrong url:

```
http://localhost:60335/Home/Index/Home/Index/?City=1
```

which is obviously wrong.

Comment: Either use `@Url.Action()` or prepend a `/`.

Comment: @CodeCaster prependiing a / works, I will check also the other answer